# Google Maps V2 API Manifest, issues.

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, manifest

I'm having issues with getting my manifest correct with V2 google maps. The error from log cat at run time i'm currently receiving is:

```
`java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the additional following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a correct behaviour:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`
```

Now I've tried a multitude of different things to get this working, however thus far I've been unsuccessful. If anybody would like to take a look at my manifest and help me out that would be appreciated.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.examples.test.night" >
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <!-- Open GL for Google Maps -->

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="***********************"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true"/>

        <!-- Creating Permission to receive Google Maps -->
        <permission
            android:name="com.examples.test.night.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />

        <uses-permission android:name="com.examples.test.night.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity2Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_activity2" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks again to anybody who can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<uses-permission>` tags must be outside the `<application>` tag.

Comment: Also note: `MAPS_RECEIVE` is unncessary as of Google Play Services 3.1.59 and can be removed completely.

Comment: Both MAPS_RECEIVE or just one?

Comment: Both the `<permission>` and the `<uses-permission>` block referencing `MAPS_RECEIVE` can be completely removed.